# Trouble with controling CSS in jQuery Mobie webapp

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm lacking experience with styling a mobile HTML5 webapp.
Everything looks ok on my browser, but since im unable to simulate in some way the real behavior of the different devices, I cant really know the real behavior of each device before i actually test it on my mobile.
It really messes up the way I can control the CSS correctly and i feel like im wasting a lot of time.

1. Is there a good way to simulate some device on the browser? note: I tried canary but it doesn't work well.
2. What I'm trying to do now is to create two simple DIV, each would be 50% of height of the screen, and each would include a background image. Whatever I'm doing, the background is always messed up.

Could anyone please provide a solution/explanation to these issues?

Comment: If you use Firefox there is a deveoper tool add on that allows you to view responsive layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [MITE](http://mite.keynote.com/download.php), a mobile emulator made by Keynote. You can download their free version and use it for emulating various mobile devices and platforms, and is frequently updated with new devices. You can even choose which device from each platform you want to test.

While Chrome, FireFox, IE 11, and other browsers do have support for testing responsive layouts and settings that you can use for emulation, I have found MITE to be an excellent tool for testing sites on emulated mobile devices, and it is my experience that MITE is a far more effective tool than the emulation support that comes with modern browsers. The QA team at my company uses this tool daily.